# jersey returns 500 when converting json in one to many relationship

Tags: java, json, hibernate, maven, jersey

I have two classes Employee and Address.

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private UserType userType;
    private Date bdate;

    public Employee() {

    }
// getters and setters

}

public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private Set<String> lines;

    public Address() {

    }
// getters and setters

}
```

I am using moxy to convert hibernate entities to json. I have enabled it in pom.xml. Also added `@XmlRootElement` on the top of entity. Below is my service code.

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{/Id}")
    public Employee test(@PathParam("Id") long Id)
    {
        return EmployeeDao.getEmployee(Id);

    }
```

Right now I am getting 500 for this service. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check log file, find Exception and add it to question.

Comment: There is no exception. However I am getting all the  data.

Comment: Please check your EmployeeDao.getEmployee(Id);  return data. it has to be in json format because you are producing json .

Comment: sop statements shows i am getting all the data but moxy unable to convert  hibernate entities to json.